# Complex array at QML

Tags: qml

I got in trouble with very simple code:

```
property var pagesAllModels: {
    ru: [
        { title: qsTr("New"),           url: "http://bash.im"           },
        { title: qsTr("Random"),        url: "http://bash.im/random"    },
        { title: qsTr("Best"),          url: "http://bash.im/best"      },
        { title: qsTr("By rating"),     url: "http://bash.im/byrating"  },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss"),         url: "http://bash.im/abyss"     },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss top"),     url: "http://bash.im/abysstop"  },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss best"),    url: "http://bash.im/abyssbest" },
    ],
    eng: [
        { title: "Latest",              url: "http://bash.org/?latest" },
        { title: "Browse",              url: "http://bash.org/?browse" },
        { title: "Random",              url: "http://bash.org/?random" },
        { title: "Top",                 url: "http://bash.org/?top"    }
    ]
}
```

That code in QML gives me error at line "eng: [" with error "expected lexem ," but in pure javascript everything work fine. What's wrong?

Comment: Be careful with this. Those are not QML objects nor JavaScript objects. Trying to modify e.g. `pagesAllModels.ru[0]` will not work. [Read more](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-variant.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your code is illegal JSON array definition. Web browsers are accepting it because they aren't strict about JS syntax, but QML engine is really strict :

In a key:value pair in associative array, the key must be a string, so it must have quotes around it, else it would be confused with a (non-existing) variable name.

```
property var pagesAllModels: {
    "ru": [
        { "title": qsTr("New"),           "url": "http://bash.im"           },
        { "title": qsTr("Random"),        "url": "http://bash.im/random"    },
        { "title": qsTr("Best"),          "url": "http://bash.im/best"      },
        { "title": qsTr("By rating"),     "url": "http://bash.im/byrating"  },
        { "title": qsTr("Abyss"),         "url": "http://bash.im/abyss"     },
        { "title": qsTr("Abyss top"),     "url": "http://bash.im/abysstop"  },
        { "title": qsTr("Abyss best"),    "url": "http://bash.im/abyssbest" }
    ],
    "eng": [
        { "title": "Latest",              "url": "http://bash.org/?latest" },
        { "title": "Browse",              "url": "http://bash.org/?browse" },
        { "title": "Random",              "url": "http://bash.org/?random" },
        { "title": "Top",                 "url": "http://bash.org/?top"    }
    ]
}
```

And it works !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
property var pagesAllModels: {
    ru: [
        { title: qsTr("New"),           url: "http://bash.im"           },
        { title: qsTr("Random"),        url: "http://bash.im/random"    },
        { title: qsTr("Best"),          url: "http://bash.im/best"      },
        { title: qsTr("By rating"),     url: "http://bash.im/byrating"  },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss"),         url: "http://bash.im/abyss"     },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss top"),     url: "http://bash.im/abysstop"  },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss best"),    url: "http://bash.im/abyssbest" }
    ],
    eng: [
        { title: "Latest",              url: "http://bash.org/?latest" },
        { title: "Browse",              url: "http://bash.org/?browse" },
        { title: "Random",              url: "http://bash.org/?random" },
        { title: "Top",                 url: "http://bash.org/?top"    }
    ]
}
```

Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: As I remember comma after last element in array is not requested in JS and it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Yup i checked and edited the answer however you using extra , in first array, and it could be the reason

Comment: No I still got error:
[W] unknown:19 -
 file:///usr/share/bashReaderOnlyQML/qml/pages/Menu.qml:19:12: Expected token `,'

Answer (score 0):

associative arrays separates by semicolon "**;**"

Try this

```
property var pagesAllModels: {
    ru: [
        { title: qsTr("New"),           url: "http://bash.im"           },
        { title: qsTr("Random"),        url: "http://bash.im/random"    },
        { title: qsTr("Best"),          url: "http://bash.im/best"      },
        { title: qsTr("By rating"),     url: "http://bash.im/byrating"  },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss"),         url: "http://bash.im/abyss"     },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss top"),     url: "http://bash.im/abysstop"  },
        { title: qsTr("Abyss best"),    url: "http://bash.im/abyssbest" },
    ];
    eng: [
        { title: "Latest",              url: "http://bash.org/?latest" },
        { title: "Browse",              url: "http://bash.org/?browse" },
        { title: "Random",              url: "http://bash.org/?random" },
        { title: "Top",                 url: "http://bash.org/?top"    }
    ]
}
```